# Nginx listen to multiple ports but rewrite to one

Tags: nginx

So I have an application running that for legacy reasons must keep it's old url with a trailing port number working.

So I have a configuration similar to this:

```
server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        listen 8080 ssl;
        server_name myurl.com;

        ssl                     on;
        ssl_certificate         /etc/nginx/conf.d/certfile.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key     /etc/nginx/conf.d/keyfile.key;
        ssl_session_timeout     5m;
        ssl_session_cache       shared:SSL:10m;
        ssl_protocols           TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        ssl_ciphers             HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;

        location / {

        proxy_pass              http://127.0.0.1:7990;
        proxy_http_version      1.1;
        proxy_set_header        Host $host;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        Location $host:443;
        proxy_redirect          off;
        }

}
```

It is working fine exept for the fact that some AJAX request made from `myurl.com:8080` will throw CRSF errors. I would like to make it so that when a user connect with 8080 port, nginx will rewrite it to 443 automatically. Is this possible to do? I have tried adding various headers but none of them seemed to do the trick.

Also tried to do a  `return       301 https://$server_name:443$request_uri;` but nginx did not like it really.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could break the server block into two, one for each port. Move common configuration into the outer block (if these are the only server blocks you have) or include common configuration with an `include` directive.

For example:

```
ssl_certificate         /etc/nginx/conf.d/certfile.pem;
ssl_certificate_key     /etc/nginx/conf.d/keyfile.key;
ssl_session_timeout     5m;
ssl_session_cache       shared:SSL:10m;
ssl_protocols           TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
ssl_ciphers             HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;

server {
    listen 8080 ssl;
    server_name myurl.com;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name myurl.com;

    location / { ... }
}
```

The `return` directive does not need a port specification if the `https` port is `443`. If `nginx` insists on adding port `8080`, try adding a `port_in_redirect off;` statement.

Comment: Just tried this my self before reading it. Seems that I got it working finally. The common directive for SSL conf is a +1. Thank you!